# Telerik Radgrid's CRUD operations (Insert, Update,Delete) by MVP pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, telerik, telerik-grid

i have a [Telerik RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) in a ASP.Net page, and i want handle CRUD event-handler in presenter of MVP pattern.

```
// ASPX page
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
         onupdatecommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand">               
</telerik:RadGrid>

// Asp.Net Code Behind
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
     // do update
}
```

Comment: Amir, your questions here need to be more specific and it should explain what's the problem you are facing. Asking such a broad question will make people vote to close it.

Comment: i think my question is clear, i need Update and Delete operation for RadGrid by MVP design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer is very easy, base on my search, we must handle grid's events(InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand) in presenter as follow:

```
// view interface
public interface IGridView 
{
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid myGrid { get; }
}

// presenter
protected readonly IGridView _view;

public GridPresenter(IGridView view)
{
    _view = view;

    _view.myGrid.UpdateCommand += new Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventHandler(onUpdateCommand);
    _view.myGrid.InsertCommand += new Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventHandler(onInsertCommand);
    _view.myGrid.EditCommand += new Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventHandler(onEditCommand);
}

private void onUpdateCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Code for updating 
}

private void onInsertCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Code for inserting
}

private void onEditCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Code for editcommand
}
```